# Number of ways a sequence can be arranged to meet the required condition

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I toss a coin 15 times and I obtain a strings of Heads(represented by H) and Tails(represented by T). I want to find the number of sequences which can be found such that there are 2 HH, 3 HT , 4 TH and 4 TT subsequences. How do I proceed?

One example of such a sequence can be TTTHHTHTTTHHTTH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any sequence with 3 $HT$s and 2 $TH$s must have the form
$$H^aT^bH^cT^dH^e$$
where $a,\ldots,e$ are positive integers, and $H^a$ represents
a sequence of $a$ consecutive heads etc. You need to find
all possible triples $(a,c,e)$ yielding 5 $HH$s and
all possible pairs $(b,d)$ yielding 4 $TT$s.

Comment: The sequence I have mentioned in the question doesn't seem to follow the pattern you have mentioned...

Comment: Your sequence does not have $2$ $TH$s. @saisanjeev

Comment: I am extremely sorry edited the question...